# How can I select a child element, but separately in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I've tried append ul into a div, but all ul append separately in div's. I want just child ul into div

Loops selected all ul's into all div's separetly.

```
<li class="first">
    <a>100</a>
    <div></div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="first">
    <a>200</a>
    <div></div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>7</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>8</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>9</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>10</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>11</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>12</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

If I use child() or any jQuery selector all ul's added into div

Only with the selector all uls are added to all divs and I can't make a selection because there is no class or id in the code.

HTML code more than 6000 lines, I tried to simplify it as much as I could

I want to this,

```
<li class="first">
    <a>100</a>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="first">
    <a>200</a>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>7</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>8</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>9</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>10</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a>11</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

I guess solved it with each and children,

```
$(".first li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().find("ul").length > 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: you want to move the `li > a + div + ul` to be `li > a + div > ul`?   `$("li>ul").each((i, e) => $(e).append($(e).prev())`

Comment: maybe you should share the code you tried. Without that, it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

As hamdi suggested, using each function in jquery is the simplest of way to do it.

```
$.each($('.first'), function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) {          
   $(valueOfElement).find("ul").appendTo($(valueOfElement).find('div'))
 });
```

This is a small example that I had used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery's `each()` method to iterate over each `li` element and find the `ul` element that is a direct child of the `li`. Then, you can move that `ul` element inside the corresponding `div` element using the `appendTo()` method.

Comment: If use this all ul elements added to all div's. Maybe i can set all class for ul's and, i shuold try appendTo with class names